# Unable to List EC2 insances via API Gateway

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-api-gateway

I am using AWS SDK Samples for "AWS EC2 Sample" in `C#`. When try to compile it gives following error. I have the latest SDK and using VS 2013.

> Error 1   'Statement' is an ambiguous reference between
>   'Amazon.IdentityManagement.Model.Statement' and
>   'Amazon.Auth.AccessControlPolicy.Statement'   c:\users\sabir.mustafa\documents\visual
>   studio
>   2013\Projects\AwsEC2Sample2\AwsEC2Sample2\Program.cs  174 33  AwsEC2Sample2
>   Error 2   'Statement' is an ambiguous reference between
>   'Amazon.IdentityManagement.Model.Statement' and
>   'Amazon.Auth.AccessControlPolicy.Statement'   c:\users\sabir.mustafa\documents\visual
>   studio
>   2013\Projects\AwsEC2Sample2\AwsEC2Sample2\Program.cs  174 43  AwsEC2Sample2
>
> Error 3   'Amazon.IdentityManagement.Model.Statement' does not contain a
>   definition for
>   'StatementEffect' c:\users\sabir.mustafa\documents\visual studio
>   2013\Projects\AwsEC2Sample2\AwsEC2Sample2\Program.cs  174 53  AwsEC2Sample2
>
> Error 4   'Amazon.IdentityManagement.Model.Statement' does not contain a
>   definition for 'Actions' and no extension method 'Actions' accepting a
>   first argument of type 'Amazon.IdentityManagement.Model.Statement'
>   could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)   c:\users\sabir.mustafa\documents\visual studio
>   2013\Projects\AwsEC2Sample2\AwsEC2Sample2\Program.cs  175 23  AwsEC2Sample2

Here is the screenshot

[image]

Comment: I guess the new AWS SDK that are referenced uses .NET Core that needs VS.NET 2015. Did you get the AWS SDK dll's via Nuget?

Comment: For VS2013, i had downloaded SDK from Amazon website.

Comment: Finally solved it.

Comment: using VB.NET and calling sdk methods to do all work. Its cool.